# How to curve a function generated by a function closure directly?

Tags: r

I am trying to curve a power function like

```
pow <- function(n) {
    function(x){ x^n }
}
```

When I curve it use the code below, everything fine

```
f <- pow(2)
curve(f,-2,2)
```

But when I curve it with

```
curve(pow(2),-2,2)
```

I get the error message "'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'", and I want to know how to curve it without a temporary variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
curve(pow(2)(x),-2,2)
```

In the documentation for `curve()`, it expects

> The name of a function, or a call or an expression written as a function of x which will evaluate to an object of the same length as x.

So `f` is the name of a function so that's why that works. You could have also called `curve(f(x),-2,2)`. But `pow(2)` is not the name of a function, it is a function call that returns a function. But when `curve` sees a function call, it expects to see that call written as a function of `x`. So by adding the `(x)` part, we turn it into a function call which `curve()` understands.